# Google BiqQuery Internal Error

Tags: google-bigquery

Edit: Tidied up the query a bit. Checked running on one day (versus the 27 I need) and the query runs. With 27 days of data it's trying to process 5.67TB. Could this be the issue?

Latest ID of error run:

> Job ID: ee-corporate:bquijob_3f47d425_1530e03af64

I keep getting this error message when trying to run a query in BigQuery, both through the UI and Bigrquery.

> Query Failed
>
> Error: An internal error occurred and the request could not be completed.
>
> Job ID: ee-corporate:bquijob_6b9bac2e_1530dba312e

Code below:

```
    SELECT
  CASE WHEN d.category_grouped IS NULL THEN 'N/A' ELSE d.category_grouped END AS category_grouped_cleaned,
  COUNT(UNIQUE(msisdn_token)) AS users,
  (SUM(up_link_data_bytes) + SUM(down_link_data_bytes))/1000000 AS tot_data_mb
FROM (
  SELECT
    request_domain, up_link_data_bytes, down_link_data_bytes, msisdn_token, timestamp
  FROM (TABLE_DATE_RANGE([helpful-skyline-97216:WEBLOG_Staging.WEBLOG_], TIMESTAMP('20160101'), TIMESTAMP('20160127')))
  WHERE SUBSTR(http_status_code,1,1) IN ('1',
    '2',
    '3')) a

LEFT JOIN EACH web_usage_201601.domain_to_cat_lookup_27JAN_with_groups d
ON
  a.request_domain = d.request_domain
WHERE
  DATE(timestamp) >= '2016-01-01'
  AND DATE(timestamp) <= '2016-01-27'
GROUP EACH BY
  1
```

Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Comment: does **select ltrim(rtrim(request_domain)) as request_domain_trim** need to be from somewhere?

Comment: Good point. Was leftover from the join I commented out but there was also a request_domain variable in the main tables so it shouldn't have created an error. I've tidied up the query and checked running it on 1 day, seems to work fine. On 27 days though get consistent errors.

The data is very big, trying to process 5.67TB, could this be the issue?

Comment: It seems like the main issue was the count(unique([var])). Even when I aggregated the table to the level of distinctness I needed, so it was only about 440m records I was still getting internal errors. Generally speaking would it be better to aggregate to this level and then do just a simple count for all queries that need a distinct count?

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be coming from UNIQUE() - it returns repeated field with too many elements in it. The error could be improved, but workaround for you would be to use explicit GROUP BY and then run COUNT on top of it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are okay with an approximation, you can also use

```
COUNT(DISTINCT msisdn_token) AS users
```

or a higher approximation parameter than the default 1000,

```
COUNT(DISTINCT msisdn_token, 5000) AS users
```

GROUP BY is the most general approach, but these can be faster if they do what you need.